# What is the effect of an amplifier on an LC tank?

Tags: transistors, capacitor, inductor, oscillator

Consider a simple circuit like this:

[image]

The tank on the right is an oscillator
and the amplifier provides in-phase "boost" to the tank to keep the oscillations going.
its controlled by the feedback from the lower capacitor.

1. When Vout starts rising above the baseline ( 0 - 90 degree of sinusoid ) the center capacitor is receiving current from the inductor and increasing its voltage.
   Flow of current is like C <== L
   now the amplifier provides in-phase push which makes Vout even higher and stronger.
2. so the amplifier action charges the center capacitor more and more. So flow is like Amplifier ==> C makes C have more voltage

But, what is the effect of the amplifier action on the inductor ?
The amplifier also sees the inductor and should push against its current ?

Red - Vout = Vc

Green - Amplifier Action

Blue = L Current

[image]

Note:

1. C gains +ve charge 0-90 deg of Vout. Current L ==> C
2. C looses +ve charge 90-180 deg of Vout. Current L <== C
3. C gains -ve charge 180-270 deg of Vout. Current L <== C
4. C looses -ve charge 270-360 deg of Vout. Current L ==> C

Comment: What sort of amplifier is it? If you don't think that's important to your question then you need to go and study a bit more.

Answer (score 1):

An amplifier might be considered a voltage amplifier, whose input voltage provides an output voltage scaled by a unit-less "gain". In that case, "C" at amplifier output does nothing, and can be eliminated.
Such an oscillator topology is not useful - at the resonant frequency of the remaining L & C, amplifier feedback has the wrong phase.

However, a transconductance amplifier does provide a useful tool to examine oscillation. Now the "C1" capacitor is relevant and *must* be included in the equivalent circuit...current from amplifier output can produce a voltage where it meets "L1". The resonator now consists of two "C" and one "L". This kind of useful oscillator is ubiquitous - often called "Pierce".
[image: two circuits (right is useful Pierce]

 I have added a resistor to illustrate resonator losses, which are compensated by gain of the transconductance amplifier. If you change amplifier gain from -0.001 to some other value, you can achieve either damped oscillation or continually-growing oscillation.

Answer (score 0):

To me it is not quite clear what you are asking - however, perhaps the following helps:

In your circuit, I cannot see any resistive part (and losses within the inductor as well as capacitor can never be avoided).

Hence. you have no IDEAL tank circuit - and it is the purpose of the amplifier to compensate all the losses (which are not shown in your circuit).

Technically spoken: Each oscillator needs a loop gain of unity at a certain frequency - and this makes an amplifier necessary. Due to unavoidable losses a passive circuit can never have unity loop gain without an amplifier.